# Divide the dataframe by different possible combinations and get random few percent of data for all the combination in seperate dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data like this:

```
age  gender  salary
 23    M     10,000
 23    M     11,000
 26    F     15,000
 26    F     10,000
 26    F     12,000
 23    M      8,000
 27    M     11,500
 27    M     13,000
```

result must look something like this:

```
age  gender  salary
 23    M     10,000
 26    F     15,000
 27    M     11,500
```

The result must be random values from the same combination excluding salary column, i.e age and gender. The salary column may have any other values for the same combination.
**Ex:** for age: 23 and gender: M, the salary may have random values such as 10,000 or 11,000 or 8,000.

Comment: In other words, you want to group by age and gender and select one sample from each group?

Comment: yes. Exaclty..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can issue:

```
>>> df.groupby(['age', 'gender']).apply(pd.DataFrame.sample).reset_index(drop=True)
   age gender  salary
0   23      M   8,000
1   26      F  10,000
2   27      M  11,500
```